# zIndex Bug or I am just stupid

Tags: react-native, z-index, react-native-ios

I tried to make an card which expands to fullscreen. I thought this would be an easy job with zIndex, but no it wasn't. My component behaves like I didn't applied zIndex to it. I never used zIndex in a react native project before.
However, I applied the following style to my Card component:

```
{
width: responsiveWidth(100), // react-native-responsive-dimensions
height: responsiveHeight(100),
left: 0,
right: 0,
top: 0,
bottom: 0,
zIndex: 999999999999999999999999,
elevation: 10000, // In an issue they said I should try elevation, it didn't worked
margin: 0,
position: "absolute"
}
```

I made an Expo project to show my issue:
[Expo Link](https://expo.io/@noim/zindexbug)
Also an github project, I extracted it out of my current project I am working on [Github](https://github.com/TheNoim/zIndexBug)
[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15KRnOCOdWQhnQMA9IIforTDjcZH_k3jD/view?usp=sharing)

Is this a bug or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change the title... Show us the rest of your code, parent containers, ect.... Maybe you're overriding z-index or need `!important`. Show us a little more.

Comment: Dose `!important` work in react native? And I never used zIndex in this project before so it can't get overwritten. And I thought the github link to the simple expo project is enough or do I need to add more into the post?

Comment: No but I was just throwing the concept.